# WeakReferences, Unexpected Object deletion

Tags: java, weak-references

My Understanding with Weak References: An object can’t be marked for deletion by gc till the time all the strong references to the object are lost/deleted. Which means if at some point, an object is left to be referenced only by weak references then the object is eligible for garbage collection and the next time G.C. runs it will mark the object for deletion.

***1.Is my understanding correct?***

To validate my understanding, I created the following program with two classes.

```
public class Customer {
    private String name;
    private String ssnId;
    private String phone;

    public Customer(String name, String ssnId, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.ssnId = ssnId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSsnId() {
        return ssnId;
    }
    public void setSsnId(String ssnId) {
        this.ssnId = ssnId;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return ssnId + name + phone; 
    }

}
```

AND

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Customer cust = new Customer("ABCD", "001 ", "Phone Number");
        WeakReference<Customer> weakcust = new WeakReference<Customer>(cust);
        int i = 0;
        while(true)
        {
            if(weakcust.get() != null)
            {
                i++;
                System.out.println(i + " " + weakcust.get());
            }
            else
            {
                System.err.println("Object's deleted");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Logically this code should keep on printing the customer’s information.

To my surprise I found that even when I am not setting the cust reference to null, G.C. is deleting the object pointed out by cust. And after some time the program prints “Object’s Deleted”

***2.Why is this happening?***

I believe this could be because compiler is optimizing the code and as cust reference is not used any more in the code, compiler is setting it to null by itself.
Plz correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your strong reference object customer itself is not referenced by anyone except the weakcust (which is a weak reference). So it is marked for garbage collection .Once the customer is garbage collected , you get the behaviour u r seeing.
In a real world application your customer would be referenced somewhere and only when its de referenced , it will be garbage collected

Answer (score 0):

You are not accessing the variable `cust` after you assigned it to weakcust. The JVMs optimization noticed that you don't seem to need it anymore, so it decided to discard it afterwards.

Turning it into a static variable of `class Main` might change this behavior.